# Unable to open header file in visual studio when compiling c-program

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

In the folder with all my C-files I include the headerfile pic32mx.h in my c-files

```
#include <pic32mx.h>
```

But when compiling any of those c-files I get the error

> fatal error: 'pic32mx.h' file not found

I went into the json-file of the folder (called c_cpp_properties.json) to set the includePath for the headerfile like this (I added the second path):

```
 "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/Applications/mcb32tools.app/Contents/Resources/Toolchain/include"
            
            
        ],
```

Yet I still get the error of not being able to compile the program, the header file is not found. I am running GCC on Mac OS and the IDEA is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Replace `<>` with `""`

Comment: Using quotes targets files locally, which is not my goal, I want to reach a file that is in a distant directory.

Comment: What? No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: Alright, sorry! I understood that completely wrong. But still after using quotes, it does not work.